# Android: How can I save application wide instance state?

Tags: android

Regarding application wide state, I have read many discussions about POJO Singletons vs. subclassing Application class.

Regarding saving state, I've learned about Activity.onSaveInstanceState.

But since Application doesn't really have Lifecycle methods, how can I save state which is used from several Activities?

My first idea was to use onCreate() and onSaveInstanceState() in my main Activity, but what happens if user pauses app while being in another Activity? When the app comes back to front, only this activity, but not my main activity will be recreated, right?

Will I have to do the same onSaveInstanceState and onCreate in ALL my activites or is there another way?

Comment: yes, the CORRECT way is to use   onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState in each activity, so please if someone answers you with changing manifest with android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" please dont do so it will just be worse sooner or later since you can not possibly take care of all changes in your app (which android does by default, unless you override this in manifest/code).

Comment: have you considered using sharedpreferences?

Answer (score 1):

> how can I save state which is used from several Activities?

Update your persistent store when the data changes. There is no "instance state" that is "used from several Activities", by definition.

> My first idea was to use onCreate() and onSaveInstanceState() in my main Activity, but what happens if user pauses app while being in another Activity?

Eventually, your process gets terminated. "Instance state" (e.g., `onSaveInstanceState()`) *may* be supplied back to you again later, depending on circumstances. Anything you absolutely need to hold onto needs to be put into a persistent store (database, `SharedPreferences`, file), usually at the time that data is changed, much like how software has been written for the past 60 years.

Comment: I don't want to use persistent storage.